# HP printer appears in "other devices" instead of in "printers"

Tags: printing, printer, hp-laserjet

In "Devices and printers" my HP printer is in the "other devices" category, basically my PC doesn't identify it as a printer. I already tried to install a driver for this specific printer from official HP website several times but it didn't fix the issue. Please help, this is really frustrating:(

Printer: HP LaserJet P1005
OS: Windows 10 Home, version 20H2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out what's the problem. This printer is simply not supported by Windows 10 even though there's an option to download a Windows 10 driver on official HP website. When I tried to search for the driver through control panel, I was browsing through many many HP printers but this specific model was not even there. For anyone who has the same problem, don't forget to first look for driver though the control panel and if you cannot find your model there, it is most likely not supported by your OS. Anyways, thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove it and then add it through the [HP-Smart Software](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/hp-smart/9wzdncrfhwlh?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

Comment: I tried, it didn't work:/ It says the USB cable is not connected to the printer.

Comment: @Alex have you tried it on a different device?

Comment: yes I just tried it on brother's laptop. It does the same thing. I see the printer in category "other devices". I install the driver, but the installation process stops in the middle and the printer is still not recognized as a printer.

Comment: @Alex I would try to contact support. Maybe they can help.